# Dropbox integration in custom PHP app

Tags: php, dropbox

I am working on a PHP app in which I need to use Dropbox web service. The requirement is that when user clicks on 'Integrate with Dropbox' link, Dropbox login popup should be shown and after successful login, it should show an other popup in which user can select Dropbox folder. Then when user uploads file from my custom PHP app, that file should get stored in selected Dropbox folder.

In all this process, user should not be redirected away from my custom PHP app.

How can I achieve this?

Do I need to create login popup for dropbox, or drop box provides one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find all the info about logging a user and uploading data here:

[Dropbox - Using the Core API in PHP](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php)

As you can see you should create an app, get an access token (trough OAuth2 flow) and use this one to make API requests on behalf of the user. If you need to keep your user on your site you can involve Ajax to build a structure to make the calls for login, authorization, etc..

Basically these are the steps:

```
// Include Dropbox PHP Sdk and create a new AuthBase instance (WebAuthNoRedirect is a subclass of).
$dropboxAppAuth = new dbx\WebAuth($yourAppInfo, "examples-authorize", new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token'););

// Get an authorize url
$authorizeUrl = $dropboxAppAuth->start();

// Invite the user to authorize your app via this url 
echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
...

// and get an access token from the GET array.
list($accessToken, $userId, $urlState) = $webAuth->finish($_GET);

// Now you need a Client instance to make you call using the API interface
$dropboxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "examples-authorize");
$accountInfo = $dropboxClient->getAccountInfo();

// Get a file pointer resource from the resource you want to upload and send it using the `uploadFile()` method from the Dropbox API
$resourceFilename = 'my-data.txt';
$f = fopen($resourceFilename, "rb");
$result = $dropboxClient->uploadFile("/".$resourceFilename, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
```

However at the end of that page you can find this basic example, complete and ready to start to play with it.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Now I have directed user to auth url, from my PHP app. Dropbox asked for login and after login it asked for allow or deny. I allowed and it showed authorization code, but it did not redirect to my app. It should redirect to my app with authorization code. Is there any step I missed?

Comment: Yes, sorry but I used the  `WebAuthNoRedirect` where I should have use the right one, `WebAuth`. I edited the answer, as u can see now you must also pass a csrf class in the constructor. and then u can access the GET array in the redirected url. Please have a look here for detailed infos on how to use this class: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/Dropbox/WebAuth.php

Comment: Yes, now is redirecting to redirect uri. I need to use dynamic redirect uri. But Dropbox is not permitting this. Can we send some details in redirect uri for creating desired uri after redirecting to static redirect uri?

Comment: Well done. Not sure I got the point but If you need to redirect again after the redirection to the "static redirectUrl" you can use the `header("Location: set your uri here")` function

Answer (score 0):

Did you research the Dropbox API?

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver

You can't do it using PHP alone, you need AJAX to save data to Dropbox.